# Swift 2 : MBProgressHUD Refresh later Error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, mbprogresshud

My codes under and working success when first open view controller but when later refresh gives error :

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
```

My codes Here

```
import UIKit

class RecipeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView?
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    var dataArray:NSMutableArray!
    var recipeId:NSString!
    var titleString:NSString!
    var pagingCount:NSInteger!

    var isFromSearch:Bool!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        titleLabel?.text = titleString as String
        pagingCount = 0        
        self.loadMore()

    }

    func loadMore()
    {
        if (self.isFromSearch == false)
        {
            self.dataArray = NSMutableArray()
            let connection : APIConnection = APIConnection();
            MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
            connection.startRequest(String(format:"%@getRecipeByCuisineId.php?cuisine_id=%@&page=%d&count=%@",kServerURl,recipeId,pagingCount,kRecipeCount), responseBlock: { (data :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

                let jsonResult: NSArray = data as NSArray;
                if((jsonResult.valueForKey("success").boolValue) == true)
                {
                    self.dataArray.addObjectsFromArray(jsonResult.valueForKey("recipe") as! NSMutableArray as [AnyObject])
                    NSLog("%d",self.dataArray.count);
                    self.tableview?.reloadData();
                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
                }
                else
                {

                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
                }

                }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
                    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        //self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden(false)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        if ((dataArray) != nil)
        {
            return dataArray.count;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad
        {
            return 200;
        }
        else
        {
            return 160.0;
        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let identifier = NSString(format:"%@%d","cell",indexPath.row)

        var cell:RecipeCell? =
        tableview?.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier as String) as? RecipeCell

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = RecipeCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:identifier as String)
        }

        cell?.recipeId = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipeid") as? String
        cell?.cuisinesId = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("cuisineid") as? String
        cell?.lblRecipeName?.text = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipename") as? String
        cell?.lblRecipeTime?.text = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("prep_time") as? String

        let str = String(format:"%@%@",kDownloadCategoryImage,dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipe_image") as! String)
        let block: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) -> Void in

        }

        cell?.recipeImage!.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: str), completed: block)

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let cell:RecipeCell? = tableview?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? RecipeCell

        let recipeDiscriptionVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("recipeDiscriptionVC") as! RecipeDiscriptionViewController
        recipeDiscriptionVC.isFromFavorite = false
        recipeDiscriptionVC.recipeId = cell?.recipeId
        recipeDiscriptionVC.titleString = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipename") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.recipeName = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipename") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.recipeDesc = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipe_desc") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.recipeIngredients = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipe_ingredients") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.prepTime = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("prep_time") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.cookingTime = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("cooking_time") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.method = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("Method") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.recipeImage = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("recipe_image") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.videoLink = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("video_link") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.ratings = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("ratings") as? String
        recipeDiscriptionVC.ratingCounter = dataArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("rating_counter") as? String

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(recipeDiscriptionVC, animated: true)
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

        let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

        if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0) {
            // For Pagging
            pagingCount = pagingCount + 1
            self.loadMore()

        }

    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false
    }


    @IBAction func btnBackTap(sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

And I think error area here, when refresh later **click item**  gives empty array error. I try but i don't resolve it.

```
func loadMore()
{
    if (self.isFromSearch == false)
    {
        self.dataArray = NSMutableArray()
        let connection : APIConnection = APIConnection();
        MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
        connection.startRequest(String(format:"%@getRecipeByCuisineId.php?cuisine_id=%@&page=%d&count=%@",kServerURl,recipeId,pagingCount,kRecipeCount), responseBlock: { (data :[AnyObject]!) -> Void in

            let jsonResult: NSArray = data as NSArray;
            if((jsonResult.valueForKey("success").boolValue) == true)
            {
                self.dataArray.addObjectsFromArray(jsonResult.valueForKey("recipe") as! NSMutableArray as [AnyObject])
                NSLog("%d",self.dataArray.count);
                self.tableview?.reloadData();
                MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
            }
            else
            {

                MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
            }

            }) { (error : NSError!) -> Void in
                MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

plz use svprogresshud instead of mbprogresshud

Link: https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD

Comment: problem not in MBprogressHUD, the problem is **self.dataArray** in here data is missing somewhere , please modify your answer

Comment: Question is asked for MBProgressHUD, not for alternatives of MBProgressHUD.